# PHP ini setting force print the php code direrly?

Tags: php, ini

in php ini, which seeting will force print the php code direcly in html?

i found that some of my code which using obstart will have this problem

but if i copy the other server php.ini, it play normally

Comment: You want your PHP code to *not* be evaluated...?!

Answer (score 1):

In httpd.conf

```
// comment out this line
# AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration setting that will print your code directly into HTML.

There may be an issue with using short open tags (eg `<? ... ?>`) in your code and not enabling them in configuration, but that's all I can think of.

Anything else would be the fault of your server configuration and / or modules.